# Snippet with function name

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to add user code snippet and I want to have the function name in it, something like this:

```
{
    "Print to console": {
        "prefix": "clog",
        "body": [
            "console.log('CONSOLE', '$FUNC_NAME$', $1);"
        ],
        "description": "Log to console"
     }
}
```

I can't find how to get the function name in VSCode snippets.

Any help?

Comment: Would this be printed anywhere n the function or predictably right after the function declaration?  If the later there might be a way to do it.  What language are you using? 
 There is no built-in way to do this.  Perhaps an extension could do the function lookup.

Comment: exactly what I wanted to ask , unfortunately no good answer so far ...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write an extension to do this. VS Code's user snippets cannot access program structure information, such as class or function names.

Check out the [completions extension sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/completions-sample) to get started.